# Understanding margin-collpasing

Tags: css, margin

I have successfully gotten the margin of the h2 element to be contained within its container - the section element. This way it doesn't collapse with the margin of the p element. I've done this by setting the `overflow` of the section element to `auto`.

My questions are:

1. Since elements with `overflow` set to anything other than `visible` can't have their margins collapsed, why does the effect I've successfully achieved only work when the container (section) element is set to `auto`? Why does it not work when the h2 element is set to `auto`?
2. When we take away the margin of the p element, and don't have `section` set to `auto`, h2 loses its upper-margin. Why does this happen? It doesn't seem to be in contact with another margin which would make it collapse.

Have a look at the codepen if it helps!
https://codepen.io/rfrostr/pen/XWmzewp

```
<header>
  <p>I am a p element.
  </p>
</header>

<section id="profile-section">
 <h2>I am a h2 element</h2>
</section>
```

Comment: 2. The `h2` still _has_ its margin, when you hover it in dev tools, you can clearly see that. But it collapses _through_ the section, so that effectively the section now has a margin-top, that keeps it away from the header. (This is actually more the “adjoining margins” portion of https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/box.html#collapsing-margins, than actual “collapsing”.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Since elements with overflow set to anything other than visible can't have their margins collapsed, why does the effect I've successfully achieved only work when the container (section) element is set to auto? Why does it not work when the h2 element is set to auto?

This is not true. overflow will disable the margin collapsing between the element and its inflow first (or last) child and not with its siblling. Overflow create a Block Formatting Context and this will isolate all the elements inside from any outside interaction.

```css
h2 {
  margin:10px 0;
  overflow:auto; /* this will do nothing */
}

.box {
  margin:10px 0;
  outline:1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
<h2>some text</h2>
<h2>some text</h2>
</div>

<div class="box" style="overflow:auto;">
<h2>some text</h2>
<h2>some text</h2>
</div>
```

In the above example, all the margin will collapse but not the ones between the second section and its childs h2.

> When we take away the margin of the p element, and don't have section set to auto, h2 loses its upper-margin. Why does this happen? It doesn't seem to be in contact with another margin which would make it collapse.

The h2 will collpase with the margin of section which is 0 and the resulting margin will be moved to section:

```css
p {
  margin: 0;
} 

section {
  /*overflow: auto;*/
  background:red;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <p>I am a p element
  </p>
</header>

<section id="profile-section">
 <h2>I am an h2 element</h2>
</section>
```

Even if an element has a margin equal to 0 it can collapse with other margin:

Comment: Thanks for your response. I'm aware W3C documentation exists talking about it but I can't quite understand what they're saying. Are you aware of any resources to pass on about margin-collapsing that could help a beginner out like me?

Comment: @rfrostr I don't really have any particular source but always try to find ones with figures (ex: https://seifi.org/css/understanding-taming-collapsing-margins-in-css.html) and always try to test case by case. By the way, you don't need to know everything because it's not useful. You will face them on the road and understand them with practise. Reading a lot of information won't help you if you don't practise.

Comment: Okay so with regards to '2.'... Would you be able to point out to me where in the W3C Doc it says this type of thing will happen? The brand new rule I can only deduce from this example is that a child element's vertical padding can be 'added onto' the parent's margin (or as someone else commented - go through the parent)  in the right conditions. I also remember it being said the root element is exempt from this rule i.e. 20px of margin-top on `body` will be respected and the body will shift down from 20px from the `html` element.

Comment: @rfrostr *The top margin of an in-flow block element collapses with its first in-flow block-level child's top margin if the element has no top border, no top padding, and the child has no clearance.*  https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/box.html#collapsing-margins

Comment: Awesome. Well that's a small victory today, I think I got what was covered. Appreciate your help.